# Why dont i get curves on the graph editor?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

Whenever I do an animation the graph editor gives me curves.

[image: Curves]

But im not getting any curves.

[image: no-curves]

Comment: Is it possible that the changes are so small that thy don't quite show on the graph? Try scaling the graph view on the Y axis.

Comment: When i clicked on the normalize it gave me the curves thanks.

Comment: You have to click the normalize button and scale it out with CTRL + Middle mouse button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some curves may not be visible due to their high value, or too low value.

First of, check if you see all curves by adjusting vertical zoom, with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>, then drag up / down.

Also, you can check the `Normalize` button at the bottom toolbar of the graph editor, and all curves will be clamped between -1 and 1 so you can see them all in a more condensed area of the graph.

Answer (score 4):

Pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> will zoom the view to make all keyframes visible. For smaller/laptop keyboards without a home key this can also be found in `View->View All`

You can use the scroll wheel to zoom the graph editor in/out or use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> and drag up/down to zoom the values or left/right to zoom frames.

It is most often the rotation values that are large, one way to keep them in range with other keyframes is to work with radians instead of degrees or to use Quaternion rotations.

Radians can be enabled in the scene properties under units. This option allows you to change between degrees and radians as you want.

[image]